# Mouse Click Loops using buttons (C#)

Tags: c#, button, loops, mouse

I'm a tad new to C# so please bear with me!

I am writing a program to send code via RS232 to a home made telescope mount.

The issues I have at the moment is hopefully very simple (But quite difficult for me!)

As an example say I have a button, I want to execute a loop when the left mouse button is held down, (which will be a continuous stream of 232 data), then when the left mouse button is released I need the loop to stop and to execute another line of code.

I sincerely hope that information I have given is enough and somebody is kind enough to help me along (I have searched the internet for answers believe me!)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into the MouseDown and MouseUp events on the button.  The MouseDown event should spawn a thread, or signal to the thread to begin executing the loop.  The MouseUp event should signal to the thread to stop executing the loop.

Something like this:

```
public class InterruptibleLoop
{
    private volatile bool stopLoop;
    private Thread loopThread;

    public void Start() {
        // If the thread is already running, do nothing.
        if (loopThread != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset the "stop loop" signal.
        stopLoop = false;

        // Create and start the new thread.
        loopThread = new Thread(LoopBody);
        loopThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        // If the thread is not running, do nothing.
        if (loopThread == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Signal to the thread that it should stop looping.
        stopLoop = true;

        // Wait for the thread to terminate.
        loopThread.Join();

        loopThread = null;
    }

    private void LoopBody() {
        while (!stopLoop) {
            // Do your work here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach seems like it would work well. And it's simple enough. Start a thread on mouse down, stop it on mouse up.

Comment: I though about having the thread only pause on mouse-down, but that complicates the API a bit since the thread would continue to live until the object was properly disposed, or later finalized.  Since this is a GUI application, the constant thread creation and destruction shouldn't really affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
First create a timer with the interval set to the frequency you want it to send the data. And send the data in the tick event. Create an event for the button's mouse down event and the buttons' mouse up event. In the mouse down event, start the timer. In the mouse up event, stop the timer.

Method 2:
Instead of starting a timer on the mouse down event, start a new thread where you do a continuous loop of data sending. Stop the thread on the mouse up event.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind replies in advance :) I will get to work and report back :)

Comment: Hi all, many thanks again for your kind help, decided on using timers in the end, I have some very ugly as hell code that could make you seethe so please forgive me ;) Still learning my way but having a great time, reminds me of being a kid again on my Spectrum and Amiga .. sort of :)

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Scope_Project_Ver_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            // *** Output data timer ***
            otimer.Interval = 50;
            // otimer.Interval = isendFreq;
            otimer.Tick += new EventHandler(otimer_Tick);
            // *** Input data timer ***
            // itimer.Interval = 601;                        <- to be unchecked
            // itimer.Tick += new EventHandler(itimer_Tick); <- to be unchecked
        }

        public int b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
        public string sb1, sb2, sb3, sb4, sb5;
        public int ivorSpeed;
        public string svorSpeed;
        public int ihorSpeed;
        public string shorSpeed;
        public int isendFreq;


        private void sendDataB_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sendDataCB.Checked)
            {
                sendDataCB.Checked = false;
                if (otimer.Enabled)
                    otimer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                sendDataCB.Checked = true;
                if (!otimer.Enabled)
                    otimer.Start();
            }
        }


        void otimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort(
            "COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.Open();
            port.Write("Q"); //                         Q
            port.Write(sb1); //                         1
            port.Write(sb2); //                         2
            // Binary stuff  // Ver Speed Binary        3           
            byte[] bverbinary = new byte[1];
            byte verbinary = 0;
            verbinary = Byte.Parse(svorSpeed);
            bverbinary[0] = verbinary;
            port.Write(bverbinary, 0, bverbinary.Length);
            // End of Binary stuff for Ver Speed
            // Binary stuff // Hor Speed Binary         4
            byte[] bhorbinary = new byte[1];
            byte horbinary = 0;
            horbinary = Byte.Parse(shorSpeed);
            bhorbinary[0] = horbinary;
            port.Write(bhorbinary, 0, bhorbinary.Length);
            port.Write(sb5);  // Movement               5
            port.Close();
        }


        private void vorSpeed_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show((this.vorSpeed.Value).ToString());
            this.Text = "You changed the Vertical Speed to " + vorSpeed.Value;
            ivorSpeed = (int)vorSpeed.Value;
            svorSpeed = ivorSpeed.ToString(); 
        }

        private void horSpeed_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show((this.horSpeed.Value).ToString());
            this.Text = "You changed the Horizontal Speed to " + horSpeed.Value;
            ihorSpeed = (int)horSpeed.Value;
            shorSpeed = ihorSpeed.ToString(); 
        }

        private void scopeUp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) // Scope Up On
        {
            b1 = 2;
            b2 = 0;
            b5 = 1;
            sb1 = b1.ToString();
            sb2 = b2.ToString();
            sb3 = b3.ToString();
            sb4 = b4.ToString();
            sb5 = b5.ToString();
        }

        private void scopeUp_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) // Scope Up Off
        {

        }

        private void scopeRight_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            b1 = 1;
            b2 = 2;
            b5 = 1;
            sb1 = b1.ToString();
            sb2 = b2.ToString();
            sb3 = b3.ToString();
            sb4 = b4.ToString();
            sb5 = b5.ToString();
        }

        private void scopeRight_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void scopeDown_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            b1 = 2;
            b2 = 1;
            b5 = 1;
            sb1 = b1.ToString();
            sb2 = b2.ToString();
            sb3 = b3.ToString();
            sb4 = b4.ToString();
            sb5 = b5.ToString();
        }

        private void scopeDown_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void scopeLeft_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            b1 = 0;
            b2 = 2;
            b5 = 1;
            sb1 = b1.ToString();
            sb2 = b2.ToString();
            sb3 = b3.ToString();
            sb4 = b4.ToString();
            sb5 = b5.ToString();
        }

        private void scopeLeft_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void scopeStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b1 = 0;
            b2 = 0;
            b5 = 0;
            sb1 = b1.ToString();
            sb2 = b2.ToString();
            sb3 = b3.ToString();
            sb4 = b4.ToString();
            sb5 = b5.ToString();
        }

        private void sendFreq_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "You changed the send Freq to " + sendFreq.Value + " m/s";
            isendFreq = (int)sendFreq.Value;
        }
    }
}
```